# ifstream constructor taken a char* but not a std::string

Tags: c++, stream

Is there any reasons - other than historical - to justify the fact std::ifstream/std::ofstream class take a char* and not a std::string to be constructed?

Comment: Just to note, they take both in C++11.

Comment: Step 1: Get C++11. Step 2: Use the `std::string` constructor. Step 3: ??????? Step 4: PROFIT

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.  The constructor from `std::string` was [added in C++11](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/basic_ifstream).